IDF tickets, 2 phones but same account, does that work?
We travel with my wife to Paris and I bought 2 Orly airport tickets with the IDF app to my Smartphone. I planned to buy the Navigo Easy card at our arrival in Paris and wanted to upload the Orly tickets onto the 2 Navigo cards. Apparently, this is bot possible, as one can only buy a ticket directly either to Smartphone or to the Navigo. Is that correct? or there is a way to transfer from my account the 2 tickets on 2 different Navigo cards?
My wifes phone supports NFC, so I tought, alternatively she can login to my account from her phone if she Downloads the app. So we can use simultanously both phones but one Account (mine) to travel. Is this going to work? Thanks for your hintss. Marcell

No, it's not possible to transfer the tickets stored on your phone to a Navigo card.
There are operating system-dependent mechanisms to restore your tickets if you changed phones within the same brand, but I doubt it will keep working on both yours and your wife's in parallel (provided you have the same brand). The tickets seem to be stored on the device itself, not with the provider on a server. The restore operation is a transfer, not a duplication.
Maybe you can go to a RATP desk and explain your problem, but expect some kind of "it's the system, not me" response ;)

Thank you for your answer. What do you mean with provided you have the same brand? She got a samsung and I a xiaomi. If we try to enter, will the system block the 2nd one who wanna pass the gate at the airport train station?  Obviously, it will be difficult to discuss at the airport, and I ex0ect the same answer you mentioned. I wanted to buy it for the complete family, we are travelling 5 of us, but in this case this is not possible, very disappointing. Could I save the 2nd ticket somehow with this restore? If I claim I changed my phone? What is the ticket validity, do you know that? Thanks!

Yes sorry, I wrote same brand because I was thinking of Apple <-> Apple but it's really same OS (Android or iOS). Regardless, it's not relevant because I don't think you can transfer only one ticket that way.

I didn't realize it at first but your question stems from the fact that you cannot use the same phone for multiple tickets, right? Maybe you should then edit the Q to reflect it.

I don't know the ticket validity but it's probably mentioned somewhere in the apps or on their website.

If we try to enter, will the system block the 2nd one who wanna pass the gate at the airport train station?  -> long story short, you won't even be able to have the tickets on the 2 phones at the same time, so this will not happen.

so in this case one of my tickets will be lost, unless I visit Paris again? no other solutions? Thanks for your supports.

Looks like it :/ Unless you only bought 2 one-way tickets and use the first on arrival Orly-Paris and the second one when you leave. Yes this limitation is ludicrous and has been pointed out by consumer organisations. It also looks the same for the Navigo Easy pass by the way.

@BaloghMarcell https://www-iledefrance--mobilites-fr.translate.goog/aide-et-contacts/passe-navigo-easy/voyage-groupe-famille?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp

Alright, thanks for the feedback. I planned to buy 4 Navigo cards, its not about that. Just why cant I distribute the tickets to my family, after purchasing them with 1 click on my mobile. Luckily, we fly back from another airport. :/ Its really strange how non-userfriendly the complete public transportation system in Paris is. So many apps and possibilities, feels like a chaos to me. Anyway, thanks for your answers!

No worries, I hope you and your family will enjoy Paris despite its quirks ;)
